# Setting the location value in <mvc:resources> using the SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web, spring-security

I am using the file system to put uploaded images for my webapplication. I am configuring the the file system in `.properties` file.
Value is in properties file

```
  IMAGES_BASE_PATH = D:/engagementjunction/images
```

And Spring Configuration

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

            <property name="location">
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </property>
            <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        </bean>
```

And I am getting the configured value as

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:///${IMAGES_BASE_PATH}" />
```

When I start the application it shows that resource not found.
When I put the  `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. It leads me to the error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42945fc0 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42945fc0 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42945fc0 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062.mvcContentNegotiationManager(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerMapping$24(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062$$FastClassByCGLIB$$fe4cf875.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062.requestMappingHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 33 more
May 05, 2014 2:54:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42945fc0 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42945fc0 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42945fc0 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062.mvcContentNegotiationManager(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerMapping$24(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062$$FastClassByCGLIB$$fe4cf875.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062.requestMappingHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 33 more

May 05, 2014 2:54:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /web threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42945fc0 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062.mvcContentNegotiationManager(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerMapping$24(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062$$FastClassByCGLIB$$fe4cf875.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4d9ad062.requestMappingHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

---

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Engagement Junction</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            com.hm.ej.config.AppConfig
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ejServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/ejServlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ejServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<web-app>
```

Comment: Could you post the error as well?

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:9090/web/images/step-box-bg.png"

Comment: And I take it that `step-box-ng.png` exists under `D:/engagementjunction/images`?

Comment: Have you added `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to spring configuration?

Comment: yes I put but it leads me to the error. See the edit.

Comment: Could you post web.xml as well?

Comment: Also, the full Spring configuration would help

Comment: Do you have @EnableWebMvc on AppConfig perhaps?

Comment: Yes I have @EnableWebMvc .

Comment: Remove it, and keep `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in XML. Let me know what happens

Comment: It's not working. It resolved the exception but the images are still not being picked.

Comment: That's good, one step at a time. Keep that configuration and check what happens when you hard code the path instead of using Spring EL.

Comment: It works properly when I hard code it.

Comment: Ok, now replace your property placeholder bean with  ` <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:application.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>`

Comment: Let me know what happens so I can create an answer if all goes well in order to help future readers with the issue

Comment: It's not working. when I replace this with EL

Comment: Sorry try `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:application.properties" ignore-unresolvable="false" ignore-resource-not-found="false"/>` and let me know if there is any error

Comment: Yeah I replaced the config file with my file name :). It's not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52008/discussion-between-geoand-and-pradeep-kr-kaushal)